# Only allow ARM to access blob Storage Account?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account

We are deploying a `Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates@2022-07-01` via an ARM template (written in Bicep if that matters) that will be used as an image to deploy VM's. This template is deployed as part of a DevOps pipeline.

Within the ARM template is a `ImageTemplatePowerShellCustomizer` that uses `Invoke-WebRequest` to download a blob from one of our Storage Accounts via SAS.

We'd like to enable the Storage Account's firewall to only allow the ARM service to read from the Storage Account, preferably at the time it needs to.

What's the best way to go about this?

**Things I've considered:**

Tried getting the public IP as the imageTemplate was being deployed and it looks to be coming from multiple huge CIDR blocks, e.g. 20.232.115.60/10 based on ARIN lookup. Using Microsoft's list of IP ranges, it appears to be coming from the AzureCloud service, which contains 7051 IPv4 CIDR blocks. We could potentially use `Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule` to add all 7051 blocks into the Storage Account's firewall as a last resort. Just wondering if there's a better way...

Answer (score 0):

> Only allow ARM to access the blob Storage Account?

To allow ARM to access blob storage, you can make use of Virtual Network Service Endpoints and Storage Account Firewall rules.

Go to portal -> storage account -> networking -> select Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses -> Add your virtual network and subnet and enable service endpoints like below:

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Once you enable Virtual Network Service Endpoints for Azure Storage on that Subnet, this will allow traffic from that Subnet to access your Storage Account over a private connection, rather than over the public internet.

Also, you can use the below PowerShell commands to update the Azure storage account firewalls or selected virtual networks and IP addresses:

```
Update-AzStorageAccountNetworkRuleSet -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -Name "mystorageaccount" -DefaultAction Deny
Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -Name "MyVNet1" | Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "mysubnet" -AddressPrefix "10.0.0.0/24" -ServiceEndpoint "Microsoft.Storage.Global" | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -Name "myvnet" | Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "mysubnet"
Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -Name "mystorageaccount" -VirtualNetworkResourceId $subnet.Id
```

**Reference:**
[Configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: I don't think this works. Using Azure Service Endpoints, you can create representations of Azure services including Storage Accounts, SQL Databases, Key Vaults, etc. However, documentation does not include the ARM service. I'm not attempting to allow another storage account to access this storage account. I need to allow the ARM service to access the storage account. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview

Comment: To allow you to access the Storage Account over a private connection without going over the public internet.  reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints